# R: problems with combining values from two dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames. The first one contains information on acquisitions:

```
transactions <- data.frame(ID=c('XXXX-2000', 'XXXX-2000', 'XXXX-2001', 
'XXXX-2002', 'YYYY-2000','YYYY-2000'),
                       Company = 
c('XXXX','XXXX','XXXX','XXXX','YYYY','YYYY'),
                       Year = c(2000, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2000, 2000),
                       Crossborder= c(1,0,0,1,1,0),
                       Relatedness = c(3,2,0,2,1,1),
                       Target.size = c(50,49,25,33,290,440))

       ID   Company Year Same.country Relatedness Target.size
XXXX-2000    XXXX 2000           1           3          50
XXXX-2000    XXXX 2000           0           2          49
XXXX-2001    XXXX 2001           0           0          25
XXXX-2002    XXXX 2002           1           2          33
YYYY-2000    YYYY 2000           1           1         290
YYYY-2000    YYYY 2000           0           1         440
```

The other data frame has financial information on the acquiring companies

```
financials <- data.frame(ID=c('XXXX-1999','XXXX-2000','XXXX-2001', 'XXXX- 
2002','YYYY-1999','YYYY-2000'),
                     Company = c('XXXX','XXXX','XXXX','XXXX','YYYY','YYYY'),
                     Year = c(1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 1999, 2000),
                     Acquiror.size = c(500,500,500,1000,1500,1500))

    ID      Company Year Acquiror.size
 XXXX-1999    XXXX 1999           500
 XXXX-2000    XXXX 2000           500
 XXXX-2001    XXXX 2001           500
 XXXX-2002    XXXX 2002          1000
 YYYY-1999    YYYY 1999          1500
 YYYY-2000    YYYY 2000          1500
```

In my first step I would need to create new columns to the transactions data frame, with information of the a) relative size of the acquiror and the target and b) then weigh the Same.country and Relatedness columns by the relative size:

```
ID       Company Year   Target.size  Rel.size Same.country weighed.Same.country Relatedness weighed.Relatedness
XXXX-2000    XXXX 2000          50    0.100        1          0.100                  3                0.30
XXXX-2000    XXXX 2000           5    0.010        0          0.000                  2                0.02
XXXX-2001    XXXX 2001          50    0.100        0          0.000                  0                0.00
XXXX-2002    XXXX 2002           5    0.005        1          0.005                  2                0.01
YYYY-2000    YYYY 2000         150    0.100        1          0.100                  1                0.10
YYYY-2000    YYYY 2000          75    0.050        0          0.000                  1                0.05
```

**I have trouble constructing the Rel.size column as the input for the acquiror size comes from another data frame which is not in the same format as the acquisitions data frame**

The final step is to create new columns to financials data frame with a) count of the transactions during each year, b) count of the transactions during previous three years, c) average of the weighed.same.country of transactions during three previous years and d) average of the weighed.relatedness of transactions during three years:

```
ID          Company Year Acquiror.size No.of.Transactions Trans.sum.3.year ave.weighed.same.country ave.weighed.relatedness
XXXX-1999    XXXX 2000           500                  0               NA                       NA                      NA
XXXX-2000    XXXX 2000           500                  2               NA                       NA                      NA
XXXX-2001    XXXX 2001           500                  1                3     0.033333333333333333       0.106666666666667
XXXX-2002    XXXX 2002          1000                  1                4                  0.02625                  0.0825
YYYY-1999    YYYY 2000          1500                  0               NA                       NA                      NA
YYYY-2000    YYYY 2000          1500                  2               NA                       NA                      NA
```

So far I have had success in constructing No.of.Transactions and Trans.sum.3.year columns, but  **I have trouble in finding the correct way to do the average of the weighed columns.**

Thank you in advance, I appreciate all help!

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your description of the problem, but the `dplyr` package can easily achieve what you want using `left_join`, `group_by` and `mutate`.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @gatsky the best package to use here would be `dplyr`. If I understood correctly what you are trying to do, this should be the code. The additional count of transactions can also be added through mutate. Note that you call the same column as 'Crossborder' and 'Same.country' in different places.

```
library(dplyr)
newtransactions <- transactions %>%
      left_join(financials, by = c("ID", "Company","Year")) %>%
      mutate(Rel.size=round(Target.size/Acquiror.size, digits = 2),
      weighed.Same.country = case_when(Same.country == 1 ~ round(Rel.size, digits = 2),
                                       TRUE ~ 0),
      weighed.Relatedness = round(Rel.size*Relatedness, digits=2))
```

Comment: Thank you. I am now able to do the first step with your and @gatsky's kind advise. However, now I would need to construct the ave.weighed columns, i.e. I need to have the average weighed.same.country and and weighed.relatedness of all transactions made during the past three years for each company. The desired output is on the final data frame in my OP.

Comment: If you give me the formulas that you use to calculate all of these, I can write the script for creating those columns. Also would you be able to add the No.of.Transactions  and Trans.sum.3.year to the data you provided.

Comment: Average.weighed.same.country:

For each company each year:

**Ifelse(the company has three consecutive years, calculate average weighed.Same.country of all transactions made during these three years, return NA)**

Same for average.weighed.relatedness

^^is this formula specific enough?

Comment: Could you clarify what the `No.of.Transactions` and `Trans.sum.3.year` are based on? I assume the `No.of.Transactions` is the total number of acquisitions each company has had but what exactly does `Trans.sum.3.year` represent ?

Comment: Yes. No.of.Transactions = number of acquisitions for each company each year. Trans.sum.3.year = number of acquisitions during the focal and two preceding years for each company each focal year, returns NA if there are not two preceding consecutive years before the company's focal year. Did it help?